# How to use default $ variables from Bulma

Tags: html, css, variables, import, bulma

I literally started my coding journey 3 days ago, so this is a whole new dimension for me.
I'm *starting* to get the hang of html and css, on the website I'm trying to design.

I'm using the **Bulma** CSS framework on my site, and I'm having trouble using their variables: http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/variables/

Are these variables only accessible in SASS? I got SASS set up, so my scss file updates my css file, but my scss file isn't associated with Bulma in any way, so I'll get "Variable is undefined", which kinda makes sense. So I'm assuming I will have to import the Bulma variables in to the scss file, but how?

This is how I got my css setup in the "head" of the html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.5.3/css/bulma.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/testing.css">
```

The only thing I'm trying to accomplish right now is to get a **black background** with the preset variable **$black**. This is from the .css file, and obviously not the way to do it, you can't use $ variables in css, right?

```
html, body {
font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
color: #dfdfdf;
background-color: $black; }
```

I guess I'm missing something basic here, help a beginner out please.

**Recap: How to use preset framework** (Bulma, in this case) **variables?**

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! And thank you for putting together one of best worded questions I've ever seen from a new user. We'll need some more info to help you I think. So your .scss files are compiling into `testing.css`, is that correct? Can you update your question with the directory structure of your project, including the `.scss` directory/files?

Comment: That is correct, my .scss files are compiling into testing.css. My project is basically in D:/folder1/folder2/projectfolder - where html.index, licenses etc. are located. In the projectfolder I also got a subfolder called assets, which again has 3 subfolders: css, img, sass, with their respective files within. There's the testing.css sheet in the css folder, and the  testing.scss file in the sass folder, nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to import the Bulma [initial-variables.scss file](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/utilities/initial-variables.sass) into your `testing.scss` file.

```
@import 'path/to/initial-variables';
```

and then you'll have access to variables like $black.

Remember to change the path so it's correct for your setup.

Comment: It's the right answer, I ended up importing every utility, as you can see in my answer above. Can't upvote you cuz of my low rep. Any insight for my second question?

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if this is the "*right*" way to do it, but **this is how I made it work**:

```
npm install bulma
```

then inserting **this** at the top of my `testing.scss` 
:

```
@import "C:/Users/username/node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all";
```

I can now use Bulma's variables in `testing.scss`, and they translate to vanilla css when saved/compiled to `testing.css`. Couldn't find any instructions for this, just something I stumbled upon. Is it like, too basic, so they assume everyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Advice: remove the Bonus Question and post a new question on Stackoverflow. Even better, search for that question, I know there are existing solutions out there.